# Override perform_create in Django Restframework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django Restframework project where User can write restaurants reviews.

Here are my models:

```
class RestaurantId(models.Model):
    maps_id = models.CharField(max_length=140, unique=True)
    adress = models.CharField(max_length=240)        
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
        

class RestaurantReview(models.Model):    
    review_author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                      on_delete=models.CASCADE)    
    restaurant_id = models.ForeignKey(RestaurantId, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class StarterPics(models.Model):
    restaurant_review_id = models.OneToOneField(RestaurantReview,
                                               on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pics_author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    restaurant_id = models.ForeignKey(RestaurantId, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name_1 = models.CharField(max_length=40)    
    picture_1 = models.ImageField()
```

My serializers:

```
class RestaurantIdSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = RestaurantId
        field = fields = '__all__'    

class RestaurantReviewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = RestaurantReview
        field = fields = '__all__'

    def validate_restaurant_review_id(self, value):        
        if value.review_author != self.context['request'].user:                       
            raise serializers.ValidationError("User has not reviewed the restaurant")        
        return value   

class StarterPicsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = StarterPics
        fields = '__all__'

    def validate_restaurant_review_id(self, value):        
        if value.review_author != self.context['request'].user:                       
            raise serializers.ValidationError("User has not reviewed the restaurant")        
        return value
```

And my views:

```
class RestaurantIdViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.RestaurantId.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.RestaurantIdSerializer


class RestaurantReviewViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.RestaurantReview.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.RestaurantReviewSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,IsAuthorOrReadOnly]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(review_author=self.request.user)


class StarterPicsViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.StarterPics.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.StarterPicsSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, IsOwnReviewOrReadOnly]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(pics_author=self.request.user)
```

What I want is that `review_author` is not able to POST a picture in `StarterPics` with another restaurant_id that the one matching the `RestaurantReview_id`.

I tried to override the `StarterPicsViewset` to do that like `restaurant_id = restaurant_review_id_restaurant_id` with no luck. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Before all `restaurant_id` field name is not good for Django models (for relational field like ForeigKey, OneToOne...), it should be `restaurant`. Django automatically adding `restaurant_id` field.

Change also other relation fields name which has `_id`.

Also your `StarterPics` model is not designed. For a user can add multiple photo to it's review for a restaurant.

```
class StarterPic(models.Model): # Don't use plural for models name
    restaurant_review = models.ForeignKey(RestaurantReview,
                                               on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)    
    picture = models.ImageField()
    # Since RestaurantReview has restaurant and user fields no need here
```

The validation should be looks like that

```
class StarterPicsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = StarterPics
        fields = '__all__'

    def validate_restaurant_review(self, value):
        user = self.context['request'].user
    
        if not value in user.restaurantreview_set.values_list('restaurant_id', flat=True): # since RestaurantReview has restaurant field 
            raise serializers.ValidationError("User has not reviewed the restaurant")        
        return value
```

Comment: I made all the changes in my code as suggested but I got a 'AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'restaurantreview'' whenever i want to POST a picture.

Comment: I edit the answer. `user.restaurantreview.values_list` should be `user.restaurantreview_set.values_list`.

Comment: My issue is now even the author of the review can't upload an image